# How to create a new BibDesk export template

Tags: bibdesk

Where do I find the current "Minimal BibTex" template for exporting a library? I want to (a) create a new version that includes URLs and DOIs, (b) name it "MinPlus BibTex", and (c) save it to wherever it needs to be saved so that it appears on the Mac, BibDesk File/Export... menu.

Comment: @jon This is a question specifically about BibDesk and its ability to export into various formats.

Comment: @AlanMunn -- Ah, yes. I think my eyes subconsciously skip over words referring to things I never use.... I'd still avoid spaces in filenames, however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't edit the Minimal BiBTeX template directly, but you can make your own template and then choose that when you export or copy items.

To do this, create a plain text file with `minimal-URL.txt` with the following content:

```
<$publications>
@<$pubType/>{<$citeKey/>,
<$requiredFields>
    <$name/> = <$bibTeXString/>,
</$requiredFields>
<$optionalFields.@nonEmpty>
    <$name/> = <$bibTeXString/>,
</$optionalFields.@nonEmpty>
<$fields.url?>
    URL = {<$fields.url/>},
</$fields.url?>
<$fields.doi?>
    DOI = {<$fields.doi/>}
</$fields.doi?>
}
</$publications>
```

Save this in `~/Library/Application Support/BibDesk/Templates` (to get to this folder when you save you can type Command-G at the file save dialogue box and it will allow you to enter the entire path.)

Now in your BibDesk preferences, go to the Templates panel, and click on the + to add a new template file.  Choose `.txt` as the file type.  You should see the following:

[image: Preferences image]

Double click to choose the file, and then navigate to `~/Library/Application Support/BibDesk/Templates` and choose your `minimal-URL.txt` file.

Now your template is available.  If you just want to use it occasionally, for individual items or groups of items,  you can always access it via the Edit menu -> Copy As -> Template -> minimal-URL.

If you want to use that as your default action for copying bib items, then you can set that in the Citation panel of the Preferences: choose Template and then pick your minimal-URL template.

It will also be available in the File -> Export menu as a possible output format:

[image: Export menu]

Comment: Alan, This is a very complete answer to my question. Many thanks!